# Can someone explain a conversion from decimal to IEE 754 Binary32?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I'm trying to convert the number **170.3** into a **IEE 754 binary32 float**:

You can see my working from the images below:

#### Converting 170 into Binary

[image]

So 170 in Binary is 10101010

#### Converting 0.3 into Binary

[image]

We can see that the pattern 1001 will repeat for ever, so we have something like

0.3 = 0.0**1001** where the bold part is recurring

#### Putting these together

When we put these numbers together, we can get the binary representation of the whole value:

170.3 = 10101010.0**1001**

where the bold part is recurring.

#### Converting this into Standard Form

[image]

170.3 = 1.01010100**1001** x 2⁷

#### How this should get stored:

This is how our 4 bytes (32 bits) are allocated:

1. The **sign** is 0, since we are working with a positive number
2. The **exponent** is 127 + 7 = 134 which in binary is 10000110
3. The **fraction** is then filled in by the first 23 bits of our recurring decimal, which in this case is 01010100**100110011001100** (where the recurring part is in bold)

So we can combine these together to get the binary data to store into our 4 bytes (32 bits):

```
01000011001010100100110011001100
```

Which, when split into 4 bytes should be:

```
01000011-00101010-01001100-11001100
```

I then try and run this C++ program, which stores the float and prints the memory:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

/* Prints Contents of Memory Blocks */
static void print_bytes(const void *object, size_t size){
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    const unsigned char * const bytes = static_cast<const unsigned char *>(object);
    #else // __cplusplus
    const unsigned char * const bytes = object;
    #endif // __cplusplus

    size_t i;

    printf("[-");
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        //printf(bytes[i]);
        int binary[8];
        for(int n = 0; n < 8; n++){
            binary[7-n] = (bytes[size -1 - i] >> n) & 1;
        }
        /* print result */
        for(int n = 0; n < 8; n++){
            printf("%d", binary[n]);
        }
        printf("%c", '-');
    }
    printf("]\n\n");
}

int main () {

    std::cout << "\nStoring a Float in Memory";
    std::cout << "\n----------------------------\n\n";

    float height = 170.3f;

    std::cout << "Address is "<< &height << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "Size is "<<  sizeof(height) << " bytes\n\n";
    std::cout << "Value is " <<  height << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Memory Blocks : \n";
    print_bytes(&height, sizeof(height));

    return 0;
}
```

But in the output, I can see that the last bit is a 1 and not a 0 as per my calculations:

[image]

And also, when using online converters, the last bit also becomes a 1:

[image]

Could someone please explain to me where I went wrong in my calculation?

Comment: If you're only off by 1, it's probably just a rounding error.

Comment: I don't think that's the case here. If we take the first 23 bits from a number with a recurring pattern, it should always be the same, right?

Comment: The first bit you dropped from the right side was a 1, so if it was rounded up instead of down your last bit would be 1.  Truncation and rounding are very different operations, and repeating patterns are irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, so the part that gets chopped off gets rounded into the final bit?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I believe IEEE-754 has some very precise rounding rules, to make sure the binary representation is the one closest to the real value.

Comment: Ohh, thanks I get it now, thanks a lot man! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone please explain to me where I went wrong in my calculation?

OP did not properly account for rounding.

Typically conversion uses the rounded value (round to nearest , ties to even)

```
 12345678 9012345678901234
+10000110.                           134
        0.0100110011001100 1 1001...     0.3
+10000110.0100110011001100 1 1001... Sum
                           v vvvvvvv
                           1 |       extra bit past the 24
                             1       "or" of the rest of the bits
+10000110.0100110011001100 1 1       Value prior to rounding
^                        ^ ^ ^       These 4 bits & rounding mode determine round value
+                        1           Round value to add (assume round to nearest, ties to even)
+10000110.0100110011001101           Sum
+ 0000110.0100110011001101           23-bit portion explicitly stored.
```

---

Amend algorithm  to 1) one more bit, the "24th" bit (starting form 0th bit) and 2) the "or" of all the lesser bits (25th, 26th, etc).

From these 2 bits, the least significant bit, sign bit and rounding mode, the proper rounding value can be determined.

Comment: `       0.010011001100110011001...    0.3
10000110.0100110011001101          Sum and round to 24 bits` -> What's happening in this part here? Are the numbers that got chopped off the end rounded into the last bit, which therefore becomes a 1?

Comment: @ganeshh123 Re-write to show steps.  (Yes the bits past the MS 24  are considered,)